# Apache-Poi word and intellij

Tags: apache-poi

How do i add the jar files to intellij properly. The program works in intellij but not as a .jar file. 
I have tried adding the files and exporting them. I dont know what to do. I've been going around in circles for the last 6 hours. Its obiously something to do with the runtime but i dont know anything about that and either there is not much information on it or (most probably) im not googling the right things.

Its this error `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument
    at Methods.word_output.createDocx(word_output.java:28)
    at Controllers.mainController.createReport(mainController.java:466)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more`

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to use a Gradle build.gradle file in the project main directory and then import the project in IntelliJ via "Import project" and choosing that file. This way IntelliJ resolves all the necessary dependencies for you.

A sample minimal Gralde build-file is

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.15-beta1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.15-beta1'

    testCompile "junit:junit:[4.12,)"
}
```

Ideally you would follow the layout of Gradle builds and put your sources in `src/main/java` and your tests in `src/test/java`.

As a bonus you gain the possibility to build the project on the commandline/CI/... whatever!